# How can I save a "complete" HTML file as single file?

Tags: html, browser, wget, utilities

Are there any utilities or web browsers that can save a file and referenced resources as a single HTML file?

With most web browsers / wget there's the option to download required CSS and images as seperate files. Is there a way to automatically inline the CSS and images?

Comment: +1 seems like an interesting question, impractical for most sites but could be useful for some.

Comment: Inline images? How is that supposed to work, base64'd in CDATA sections? Good luck convincing the browser to read that.

Comment: It seems to me this should be doable in theory. CSS and JS files can certainly be parsed and embedded in a header with some path-checking. Images can maybe be encoded to data and coded into the `<img />` tags. Not sure that I know of a single utility that will do this. Good ask though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MHTML is the format for this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: +1 IE has supported this (with extension .mht) since always ... well, since 5.0.

Comment: Note that Safari does not support

Answer (score 7):

I have made a python script for this. Up to now, it covers my own needs perfectly. Hopes to be useful.

https://github.com/zTrix/webpage2html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! <3

Answer (score 3):

This web extension might help you.

https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile

"It helps you to save a complete web page into a single HTML file."

It is available for almost all popular browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Safari (on both Windows and Mac) can create .webarchive files.

Link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to `wget`, then you likely have access to a `tar` utility too. While it won't give you a browser-readable single file, if you `wget` a page and then `tar` up all of the downloaded artifacts, you effectively have a 1-file version of everything needed for that page.